# How to display all data in shelve in order?

Tags: python, shelve

This is the first time I post in stack overflow. Perhaps I can get the solution that I need.

```
busdata=shelve.open("Database")
for lctno in busdata.keys():
    outputLine( lctno , busdata[ lctno ])
```

It randomly display the data in my .dat file. I want it to display in ascending order.

Comment: You could use `sorted(busdata.keys())` but a `shelve` is inherently unordered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As g.d.d.c suggested, the solution is to sort the keys for yourself.

```
busdata=shelve.open("Database")
my_keys = list(bustdata.keys())
my_keys.sort()
for lctno in my_keys:
    outputLine( lctno , busdata[ lctno ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the code above did not work for me - I made some tests, and thought of posting my final working result (in full) - solving the listing of all data in shelve in order:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# 

import shelve

def main():
    db = shelve.open("database.db")
    dkeys = list(db.keys())
    dkeys.sort()
    for x in dkeys:
        print ( x , db[ x ])
    db.close()
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```